# Line object is extending at the bottom of the page when data is too long in crystal reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

So I have this problem in crystal report where when the data in the bottom of the page is too long it will go to the next page but the line will just extends.

Here is the image:
[image]

As you can see, It has excess lines in the bottom page. This will happens when the data in the bottom is too long and will not fit in the first page and it will go to the next page but the line still remains. How to fix this?

Comment: Is the checkmark `Keep Together` activated on the appropriate section?

Comment: yes `Keep Together` is checked

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the lines are ending in the page footer section. So, shorten them to the section above.